# Does the array name also takes a space in memory in C?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

The figure at this video suggests that array name also takes space in memory 
https://youtu.be/HXF3XSmqB1M[image]

Comment: No. It doesn't. This is only to illustrate that array name actually points to the first element of the array. This is true in most cases but there are few exception where array doesn't converted to pointer to its first element.

Comment: @haccks That "array name actually points to the first element" is misleading. An array is an array. It can however *decay* to a pointer to its first element, but then it's no longer an array. Arrays are not pointers, and pointers are not arrays, even though both can often (but not always) be used interchangeably.

Comment: The comment in box _'2.  Also it defines a variable called `w` which stores the address of `w[0]`'_ is completely bogus.  The name of an array is a constant, not a variable, and it isn't stored anywhere per se; it is used when needed, which isn't quite the same thing.  There certainly isn't a separate memory unit that holds the address of `w`.  Ignore the video.  If it is wrong on this, it is probably wrong on other things too, and you don't need misinformation while learning.l

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude; Agreed. I didn't say this analogy is right or wrong :). I just pointed out that what it meant in the figure. There are so many video lectures and tutorials on programming languages which gives wrong information and cause the chaos among newbies.

Comment: How can anyone vote to close this because it's to broad?

Comment: @EugeneSh. while in many cases it wouldn't, it is possible for for an array name to take up space in memory. If it were a global variable, the linker would include it in the symbol table so that the dynamic loader can resolve references to it, if need be. Admittedly this probably isn't what OP had in mind, but still.

Comment: Also @haccks-  I couldn't tag both of you above

Comment: @klutt "Too broad" is, sometimes, a synonym for "This question is so basic, and has been asked so many times before, that you really shouldn't be asking it again."

Comment: @SteveSummit I think that's wrong. If it has been asked many times before, then find one of those questions and mark it as a dupe.

Comment: @klutt I voted to close it 'cause it's too broad. It's not a programming question. You posted no code and there's no problem to reproduce.

Comment: @nicomp 1) It was not me who posted the question. 2) If it's not a programming question, then close as off topic and not as to broad 3) It is a perfectly valid programming question.

Comment: @nicomp I realize that I may have sounded a bit harsh. That was not intended.

Answer (score 5):

No memory is set aside for an object apart from the array elements themselves.  If you declare an array as

```
T a[N]; // for any type T
```

then what you get in memory is

```
   +---+
a: |   | a[0]
   +---+
   |   | a[1]
   +---+
    ...
   +---+
   |   | a[N-1]
   +---+
```

There is no object `a` separate from `a[0]`, `a[1]`, etc.  Unless it is the operand of the `sizeof` or unary `&` operators, the *expression* `a` will be converted ("decay") from an expression of type "N-element array of `T`" to an expression of type "pointer to `T`", and the value of the expression will be the address of the first element of the array.  IOW, `a == &a[0]`<sup>1</sup>.

---

1. See [this paper](https://heim.ifi.uio.no/inf2270/programmer/historien-om-C.pdf) for Ritchie's motivation for this approach.  C was derived from an earlier language named B, which *did* set aside extra memory for an array object.  Ritchie wanted to retain B's array semantics, but not that extra pointer, so he devised this rule to replace the array expression with a pointer during compilation.

Comment: a is not necessarily an object

Comment: @tadman -- [C _does_ have objects](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#3.15p1), just not the OOP kind. The term _object_ shows up time and time again in the C Standard.

Comment: @tadman: I'm using the term "object" in the same sense that C uses the term "object" - a region of storage in the execution environment which may represent values.  Again, no storage is set aside for anything (i.e., any object) apart from the array elements themselves.

Comment: @JohnBode That definition confuses things more than it helps. "Object" as "storage region" applies to pretty much everything.

Comment: @tadman: Blame the authors of the C language standard, then.  You have to call actual instances in storage *something*, and "object" works as well as anything else.

Comment: @JohnBode I get that, but "object" in this very specific context (e.g. compiler design) is not what most would think of as an object (e.g. object-oriented). Not sure there's a way to differentiate here without getting really pedantic. Maybe already digressing too much, but the video that sparked this is full of confusion too...

Answer (score 4):

No, an array name does not "take space in memory".

I don't think I like that video.  Maybe it's just me, but when I see a box with an arrow in it pointing at another box, it's a pointer value pointing somewhere.  But an array is not not *not* a pointer.  (Would-be instructors often describe array names as "constant pointers", or draw misleading pictures like the ones in that video, and generations of C learners are left badly confused, imagining that arrays are pointers, and wondering where the pointer value is actually stored.)

Here are some declarations and a lovely ASCII art picture showing how I like to think about arrays and pointers:

```
int i = 5;
int *ip = &i;
int a[10] = {11, 22, 33};
int *ip2 = a;

     +-------+
 ip: |   *   |
     +---|---+
         |
         V
     +-------+
  i: |   5   |
     +-------+

     +-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
  a: |  11   |   22  |  33   |   0   |   0   |   0   |   0   |   0   |   0   |   0   |
     +-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
         ^
         |
     +---|---+
ip2: |   *   |
     +-------+
```

In this picture, the boxes are actual pieces (bytes) of memory.  The tags next to them like `i:` and `a:` are symbols.  They provide the names for specific locations in memory, but they don't take up any room themselves.

In particular, the array name `a` is the name of the location of the first byte of memory where the array's contents are stored, just like the name `i` is the name of the location of the first byte in memory where the variable's value is stored.

And, once again, the array name `a` does not take up any space in memory.  It's especially not anything like `ip2`.  `ip2` is a pointer variable which *does* take up space in memory, and which currently points into array `a`.

The trick is -- and this is indeed somewhat of a trick, but one every C programmer has to be comfortable with -- given the declarations above, we can write both `a[2]` and `ip2[2]`, and both of those expressions fetch the third value in the array, i.e. the number 33.

See also [section 6](http://c-faq.com/aryptr/index.html) in the old [C FAQ list](http://c-faq.com/), especially questions [6.3](http://c-faq.com/aryptr/aryptrequiv.html) and [6.10](http://c-faq.com/aryptr/ptrkindofary.html).

Comment: The video is pretty confused, but par for the course in YouTube land where it's the blind leading the blind.

Comment: @nicomp If you mean that the other 7 cells might contain uninitialized garbage, actually, in this case I believe they *are* guaranteed to be initialized to 0.

Comment: @SteveSummit No, they are not guaranteed to be init'd to zero.

Comment: @nicomp -- Global variables (static duration) are zero-initialized, so [members of an array with an initializer list that do not have an explicit initializer are initialized to zero.](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.9p21)

Comment: @SteveSummit Your example doesn't use global variables.

Comment: @nicomp -- SteveSummit is correct, the array does not need to be global. Read the reference to the Standard that I linked to in my above comment. Here it is again: ["If there are fewer initializers in a brace-enclosed list than there are elements or members of an aggregate, or fewer characters in a string literal used to initialize an array of known size than there are elements in the array, the remainder of the aggregate shall be initialized implicitly the same as objects that have static storage duration."](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.9p21)

Comment: @nicomp In other words, while it's true that `int a[10];` as a local variable gets you 10 ints of garbage, that same local array, if it has an initializer that initializes even one cell of it, is guaranteed to have all its cells initialized in a well-defined way, either explicitly or (as per static duration) all zero.  (I was confused on this point for a long time myself, until someone right here on SO set me straight a little while ago.)